# Website with "3 columns and 4 states" in CSS only

Tags: css, checkbox, calculated-columns

The page should have three columns: left menu, content and right menu. Both menus should be able to be hidden (using the Checkbox Hack) while the content then takes up the space. The whole page should have a maximum width of 1000px.

I've come a long way, but now I'm stuck.
The three columns result in 4 states:

0. left - content - right (250 - 500 - 250)
1. left - content (250 - 750)
2. content - right (750 - 250)
3. content (1000)

With 1 and 2, the content has to be larger by the width of the hidden column, for which I use "calc(100% + 250px)".
But how do I do that when both page columns are hidden, the content occupies the full width of the page?
Also, the page width limitation doesn't work, but that's not that important yet.

```css
:root {
  --darkgrey: darkgrey;
  --almostwhite: #fcfcfc;
  --almostwhite_font: #fcfcfc;
  --lightgrey: lightgrey;
  --blue: blue;
  --darkgrey_font: #404040;
  --lightgrey_1: #e3e3e3;
}

.red {
  color: red;
  padding: 15px;
}

.toggle-links {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}


/* ═══════════════════════════════════╝ Wrapper ╚══════════ */

body {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}


/* ═══════════════════════════════════╗ Wrapper ╔══════════ */


/* ═══════════════════════════════════╝ Header ╚══════════ */

.header {
  position: fixed;
  /* display: block;  */
  width: 250px;
  height: 120px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: var(--almostwhite_font);
  /* z-index: 200; */
  background-color: var(--darkgrey);
}

a.header_link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 25px;
  font-size: 30pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: var(--almostwhite);
}

.header .searchbox {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 65px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}


/* ═══════════════════════════════════╗ Header ╔══════════ */


/* ═══════════════════════════════════╝ three columns ╚══════════ */

.left_column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  background: var(--darkgrey);
  overflow: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.center_column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
  border: solid 1px darkred;
}

.right_column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  background: var(--darkgrey);
  overflow: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}


/* ═══════════════════════════════════╝ Small View ╚══════════ */

.left_column {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  left: -250px;
  top: 120px;
}

.center_column {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 0px);
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 25px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.right_column {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  left: calc(100% + 250px);
  top: 0px;
  padding-top: 120px;
}


/* ═══════════════════════════════════╗ Small View ╔══════════ */


/* ═══════════════════════════════════╝ Medium View ╚══════════ */

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .left_column {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 120px;
  }
  .center_column {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
    left: 250px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 25px 10px 10px 10px;
  }
  .right_column {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    left: calc(100% + 250px);
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 120px;
  }
}


/* ═══════════════════════════════════╗ Medium View ╔══════════ */


/* ═══════════════════════════════════╝ Large View ╚══════════ */

@media screen and (min-width: 1140px) {
  .left_column {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 120px;
  }
  .center_column {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 500px);
    left: 250px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 25px 10px 10px 10px;
  }
  .right_column {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    left: calc(100% - 250px);
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 120px;
  }
}


/* ═══════════════════════════════════╗ Large View ╔══════════ */


/* ═══════════════════════════════════╗ three columns ╔══════════ */


/* ═══════════════════════════════════╝ Switches ╚══════════ */

input.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div.left_column {
  display: block;
}

input[type=checkbox]#toggle_left_column:checked~div.left_column {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]#toggle_left_column:checked~div.center_column {
  left: 0px;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
}

div.right_column {
  display: block;
}

input[type=checkbox]#toggle_right_column:checked~div.right_column {
  display: none
}

input[type=checkbox]#toggle_right_column:checked~div.center_column {
  left: 250px;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
}


/* ═══════════════════════════════════╗ Switches ╔══════════ */
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- switches -->
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_left_column" class="hidden">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_right_column" class="hidden">
  <!-- switches -->

  <div class="left_column">

    <div class="header">
      <a href="header_link" class="header_link">mySite</a>
      <div class="searchbox">
        <form><input type="search" /></form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <ul>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- left_column -->




  <div class="right_column">
    <div id="menu2">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <ul>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
        <li> item </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- right_column -->


  <div class="center_column">

    <!-- just for testing -->
    <div class="toggle-links">
      <label class="red" for="toggle_left_column">toggle left side</label>
      <label class="red" for="toggle_right_column">toggle right side</label>
    </div>
    <!-- just for testing -->

    <div id="content">
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- center_column -->


</body>
```

Comment: Can you clarify : *"content With 1 and 2, the content has to be larger by the width of the hidden column, which I use "* ?

Comment: ... is this what you try to do ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wvWLwaK . grid is usefull here .

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, i added the widths in pixels after every state. Thanks for the link, i never used grid, but i will have a look at it.

Comment: I've experimented with "grid" and I'm getting very close to my idea: https://codepen.io/koljal/pen/jOWjmZp
@G-Cyrillus
But what still irritates me is that the HTML validator says: ````Element box not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)````
I can't find a solution for this, just ignore it?

Otherwise, please take a look at my code and criticize it, thanks.

Comment: <box> is not an html element even if  it works , Use any regular block element alike `<div  class="box">`  . It was there for the quick example

Comment: Tahnk you, i did so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```css
div{scrollbar-width:none;}
label {padding:.5em;font-weight: bold; font-size:120%;}
body {max-width: 1200px;margin:0px;}
a{text-decoration: none;}
#header{position:fixed; width: 250px; height:140px;  background-color: #191970;}
#header a{color: #F8F8F8;font-size: 30pt; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; padding: 10px; font-family: "Bree Serif";}
#center_content{top:22px;
    /* position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px; max-width:700px;  */
    background-color: DarkRed;overflow-y:auto;}
#full_left_side{}
#left_menu{position:fixed;width:250px;top:140px;bottom:40px;overflow-y:auto; background-color: green;}
#footer{position:fixed;width:250px;bottom:0;height:40px; background-color: DarkViolet;}

#right_menu{position:fixed;width:250px;top:22px;bottom:0px;overflow-y:auto; background-color: DarkOrange;}


.hidden {position:absolute;right:100vw}
li{list-style:none; line-height: 1.3;}
ul{padding-left:10px;}

div.grid {display:grid;grid-template-rows:1fr 0 ;overflow:hidden;}
/* .grid_item{box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px;margin:0em;height:100%;overflow:hidden;} */

.label_left_content_right,.label_left_content, .label_content_right, .label_content{display:none;}

/* show all: LCR */
/* minmax(0, 1fr) */
#left_content_right:checked ~div{grid-template-columns:250px 1fr 250px;}
#left_content_right:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div.toggle_left>label.label_content_right{display:inline;}
#left_content_right:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div.toggle_right>label.label_left_content{display:inline;}

/* show: content & right CR */
#content_right:checked ~div{grid-template-columns:0px 1fr 250px;}
#content_right:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div.toggle_center>label.label_left_content_right{display:inline;}
#content_right:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div.toggle_right>label.label_content{display:inline;}

#content_right:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div#header{left:-300px;}
#content_right:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div#left_menu{left:-300px;}
#content_right:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div#footer{left:-300px;}


/* show: left & content LC */
#left_content:checked ~div{grid-template-columns:250px 1fr 0px;}
#left_content:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div.toggle_center>label.label_left_content_right{display:inline;}
#left_content:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div.toggle_left>label.label_content{display:inline;}

#left_content:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div#right_menu{right:-300px;}


/* show: content C */
#content:checked ~div{grid-template-columns:0px 1fr 0px;}
#content:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div.toggle_center>label.label_left_content{display:inline;}
#content:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div.toggle_center>label.label_content_right{display:inline;}

#content:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div#header{left:-300px;}
#content:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div#left_menu{left:-300px;}
#content:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div#footer{left:-300px;}

#content:checked ~div.grid>.grid_item>div#right_menu{right:-300px;}
```

```html
<body>

  <span class="hidden">LCR</span><input class="hidden" type="radio" name="grid" id="left_content_right" checked>
  <span class="hidden">LC</span> <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="grid" id="left_content">
  <span class="hidden">CR</span> <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="grid" id="content_right">
  <span class="hidden">C</span>  <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="grid" id="content">

  <div class="grid">

    <div id="full_left_side" class="grid_item"><!-- left BOX -->

      <div class="toggle_left">
        <label class="label_left_content_right" for="left_content_right">LCR</label>
        <label class="label_content_right" for="content_right">CR</label>
        <label class="label_content" for="content">C</label>
      </div>

      <div id="header">
        <a href="#" class="header_link">PageName</a>
      </div>

      <div id="left_menu">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <ul>
            <li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="footer">
        <a href="#" class="footer_link">Footer1 </a>
        <a href="#" class="footer_link">Footer2 </a>
        <a href="#" class="footer_link">Footer3</a>
      </div>
    </div><!-- left BOX -->

    <div class="grid_item"><!-- center BOX -->
      <div class="toggle_center">
        <label>_</label>
        <label class="label_left_content_right" for="left_content_right">LCR</label>
        <label class="label_left_content" for="left_content">LC</label>
        <label class="label_content_right" for="content_right">CR</label>
      </div>

      <div id="center_content">
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame<br>t, consetetur sadi<br>pscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirm<br>od tempor invidunt ut labore et<br>dolore magna aliquyam erat<br>, sed diam voluptua.<br> At vero eos et accusam et justo<br> duo dolores et ea rebum.<br>Stet clita kasd gubergren,<br> no sea takimata sa<br>nctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit am<br>t. Lorem ipsum dolor sit am<br>et,consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy<br> eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,<br>sed diam voluptua. At ver<br>o eos et accusa<br>m et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,<br>no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>dolor sit amet.<br>          dolore magna aliquyam erat<br>, sed diam voluptua.<br> At vero eos et accusam et justo<br> duo dolores et ea rebum.<br>Stet clita kasd gubergren,<br> no sea takimata sa<br>nctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit am<br>t. Lorem ipsum dolor sit am<br>et,consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy<br> eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,<br>sed diam voluptua. At ver<br>o eos et accusa<br>m et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,<br>no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>dolor sit amet.<br>          dolore magna aliquyam erat<br>, sed diam voluptua.<br> At vero eos et accusam et justo<br> duo dolores et ea rebum.<br>Stet clita kasd gubergren,<br> no sea takimata sa<br>nctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit am<br>t. Lorem ipsum dolor sit am<br>et,consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy<br> eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,<br>sed diam voluptua. At ver<br>o eos et accusa<br>m et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,<br>no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>dolor sit amet.<br>          dolore magna aliquyam erat<br>, sed diam voluptua.<br> At vero eos et accusam et justo<br> duo dolores et ea rebum.<br>Stet clita kasd gubergren,<br> no sea takimata sa<br>nctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit am<br>t. Lorem ipsum dolor sit am<br>et,consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy<br> eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,<br>sed diam voluptua. At ver<br>o eos et accusa<br>m et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,<br>no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>dolor sit amet.<br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- center BOX -->

    <div class="grid_item"><!-- right BOX -->
      <div class="toggle_right">
        <label class="label_left_content_right" for="left_content_right">LCR</label>
        <label class="label_left_content" for="left_content">LC</label>
        <label class="label_content" for="content">C</label>
      </div>
      <div id="right_menu">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <ul>
            <li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li><li> item </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div><!-- right BOX -->

  </div> <!-- grid -->
</body>
```